# Is printf a static function in C?

Tags: c, static, printf, stdio, c-standard-library

I'm pretty new to C, and I know that static functions can only be used within the same object file.
Something that still confuses me though, is how if I hover over a call to printf in my IDE it tells me that printf is a static function, when I can perfectly use printf in multiple object files without any problems?
Why is that?

[image]

**Edit**: I'm using Visual Studio Code the library is stdio.h and compiling using GCC

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("Hello, world!");
  return 0;
}
```

Hovering over printf would give that hint
**Edit 2**: if static inline functions are different from inline functions how so? I don't see how making a function inline would change the fact that it's only accessible from the same translation unit
**Edit 3**: per request, here's the definition of `printf` in the `stdio.h` header

```c
__mingw_ovr
__attribute__((__format__ (gnu_printf, 1, 2))) __MINGW_ATTRIB_NONNULL(1)
int printf (const char *__format, ...)
{
  int __retval;
  __builtin_va_list __local_argv; __builtin_va_start( __local_argv, __format );
  __retval = __mingw_vfprintf( stdout, __format, __local_argv );
  __builtin_va_end( __local_argv );
  return __retval;
}
```

[screenshot of the printf definition in my IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9qpp.jpg)

Comment: What IDE?  What compiler?  What code?  You need to provide a lot more details, including enough code for others to at least try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: See where it says `inline` right after the `static`?  Static inline functions are different from static functIons.

Comment: ... But anyway, Andrew Henle is right. Your IDE is showing you a fine detail of your particular C library that the C library implementors thought would be hidden.  In order to explain what's going on and what to do about it, we need to know exactly which C library you have and exactly which IDE.

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if `static int (*f)() = printf` (in multiple .c files) would save different address?  This `static inline ...` declaration of `printf()` looks problematic.

Comment: An implementation could theoretically define `printf` as a `static inline` function (you would anyway need the "stdio.h" header in each TU that uses it). The definition of that function could include a call to a system-defined `extern` function.

Comment: Can you go to the **definition** of `printf` (maybe by right-clicking on it in your code)? Showing us that may help clarify the issue ... it *may* just be a 'wrapper' that inserts the `stdout` file as the first argument in a call to `fprintf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all the updates.  Your IDE is showing you implementation details of your C library that you're not supposed to have to worry about.  That is arguably a bug in your IDE but there's nothing wrong with the C library.

You are correct to think that a function declared `static` is visible only within the translation unit where it is defined.  And that is true whether or not the function is also marked `inline`.  *However*, this particular `static inline` function is defined *inside `stdio.h`*, so every translation unit that includes `stdio.h` can see it.  (There is a separate copy of the inline in each TU.  This is technically a conformance violation since, as chux surmises, it means that `&printf` in one translation unit will not compare equal to `&printf` in another. However, this is very unlikely to cause problems for a program that isn't an ISO C conformance tester.)

As "Adrian Mole" surmised in the comments on the question, the *purpose* of this inline function is, more or less, to rewrite

```
printf("%s %d %p", string, integer, pointer);
```

into

```
fprintf(stdout, "%s %d %p", string, integer, pointer);
```

(All the stuff with `__builtin_va_start` and `__mingw_vfprintf` is because of limitations in how variadic functions work in C.  The *effect* is the same as what I showed above, but the generated assembly language will not be nearly as tidy.)

---

Update 2022-12-01: It's worse than "the generated assembly language will not be nearly as tidy".  I experimented with all of the x86 compilers supported by [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) and *none* of them will inline a function that takes a variable number of arguments, even if you try to force it.  Most silently ignore the force-inlining directive; GCC gets one bonus point for actually *saying* it refuses to do this:

```
test.c:4:50: error: function ‘xprintf’ can never be inlined 
    because it uses variable argument lists
```

In consequence, every program compiled against this version of MinGW libc, in which `printf` is called from more than one `.c` file, will have multiple copies of the following glob of assembly embedded in its binary.  This is bad just because of cache pollution; it would be better to have a single copy in the C library proper -- which is exactly what `printf` normally is.

```
printf:
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], rcx
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+16], rdx
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+24], r8
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+32], r9
        push    rbx
        push    rsi
        push    rdi
        sub     rsp, 48
        mov     rdi, rcx
        lea     rsi, QWORD PTR f$[rsp+8]
        mov     ecx, 1
        call    __acrt_iob_func
        mov     rbx, rax
        call    __local_stdio_printf_options
        xor     r9d, r9d
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+32], rsi
        mov     r8, rdi
        mov     rdx, rbx
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rax]
        call    __stdio_common_vfprintf
        add     rsp, 48
        pop     rdi
        pop     rsi
        pop     rbx
        ret     0
```

(Probably not *exactly* this assembly, this is what godbolt's "x64 MSVC 19.latest" produces with optimization option `/O2`, godbolt doesn't seem to have any MinGW compilers. But you get the idea.)

Answer (score 1):

`__mingw_ovr` is normally defined as

```
#define __mingw_ovr static __attribute__ ((__unused__)) __inline__ __cdecl
```

It appears that this definition of `printf` is a violation of the C standard. The standard says

> 7.1.2 Standard headers
> 6 Any declaration of a library function shall have external linkage